# How to get the union of the specific fields of another union

Tags: javascript, redux, flowtype

I'm trying to have as much type safety as possible on my Redux app and I'm stuck with this problem. Basically I have these types:

```
type ActionA = { type: 'A' }
type ActionB = { type: 'B' }

type Actions = A | B
```

And I'd like to have a type `ActionType` that is the union of all the possible `type`s of my actions. i.e:

```
type ActionType = 'A' | 'B' // <-- How to get this from `Actions` ?
```

In other words, I would like to get the union of all the possible values of a field (`type`) in an union (`A | B`).

Is this even possible with flow ?

The use case is to be able to avoid misspelling actions types when I need to write them directly. For example, using `redux-saga`, I could write a definition of `take` that would be (over-simplified for the example):

```
define function take(action: ActionType, saga: Function)
```

Then I would be sure I can only call `take` with valid action types.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you're asking. However, I posted a couple of answers, which I think may satisfy your wider requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could model it like this:

```
type ActionType = 'A' | 'B'
type Action = { type: ActionType }

type ActionA = { type: 'A' } & Action
type ActionB = { type: 'B' } & Action
```

There is some duplication of literals, but I think this is unavoidable. Further, with this construction you can't make a mistake, because each action is constrained to having only one of the valid types.

Declaring an action with an unknown type like this is not, by itself, an error:

```
type ActionC = { type: 'C' } & Action
```

But it's an uninhabitable type, because `'C'` is not a valid `ActionType`, so you'd get a compile error when you try and use it:

```
let c: ActionC = { type: 'C' }; // ERROR!
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work because flow is not able to properly filter the possible action type when doing a switch case with this method (i.e: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/290#issue-95943173). I guess it's because 'type' is the union of all types so it can't properly match the action shape with its type name. I can't find a way to make it work with generics neither :(

Answer (score 0):

Another solution uses generics:

```
type ActionType = 'A' | 'B'

type Action<T: ActionType> = { type: T }

// actually you may not want to bother defining these aliases
type ActionA = Action<'A'>
type ActionB = Action<'B'>
```

If you want to abstract over the different values of `type`, then use `*`:

```
function doAction(action: Action<*>){
    ....
}
```

Note, `*` is not the same as `any`, and (unlike with `any`) Flow will be able to infer its value, so you can do things like this:

```
function getType(action: Action<*>): * {
    return action.type
}

let type1:'B' = getType({type: 'B'});   // OK
let type2:'A' = getType({type: 'B'});   // ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! I had this in mind but I was hopping I could avoid duplication of literals

Comment: Most of the reasons for not duplicating literals don't really apply in Flow. They're but much different from enums when they can be type checked.

Comment: Yep, I wouldn't mind duplicating if it matches all the points I'm trying to obtain. Basically I'd like to have: 1) filtering of action shape in reducers (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/290#issue-95943173)
2) validation of string literals. The 1st one works with my current approach but the 2nd one is quite hard to obtain in every places. It currently works when creating new actions but it can't prevent me from writing `takeAction('WRONG_ACTION')`. Ideally I would like to catch `if (type === 'WRONG_ACTION')` but that doesn't seem possible as of today with flow.